# Extract values from [ , ] using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a scenario like whenever I get a string like `[ 1234abcd , 5678efgh ]`, I want to get the values between `[ , ]` . I am using java `split` with a delimitter ",". With this I'm also getting `[` and `]`, which I don't want.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is : 1234abcd 5678efgh.

Comment: What's your expected output if the input is `[ 1234abcd , 5678efgh ],bar[foo,bar]`

Comment: input [ 1234abcd , 3456efgh] and output : 1234abcd       3456efgh, two seperate values

Comment: What about foo, bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before split first get substring like this:

```
str.substring(1, str.length()-1)
```

then use split method.

Demo example:

```
 public class StringDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "[ 1234abcd , 3456efgh]";
            str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
            String AfterSplit[] = str.split(",");
            System.out.println(AfterSplit[0]+"  "+AfterSplit[1]);
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
1234abcd    3456efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])
```

You can simply grab the middle content and then split by `,`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/7